# file_put_contents(/root/.composer/cache/repo/https---flex.symfony.com/): failed to open stream: Is a directory error

Tags: docker, symfony, composer-php, symfony-flex

I build my symfony 4 application with composer install inside docker container.

Composer version 1.10.19

But i got this error.

> [ErrorException]
> file_put_contents(/root/.composer/cache/repo/https---flex.symfony.com/): failed to open stream: Is a directory

If i run composer install 1 more time without any interruption build is succeeded.

If i delete vendor and var/cache directory on project directory error accoured again.

I tried this methods:

- trigger 'composer clearcache' command no success
- Delete ~/.composer directory no success
- chmod -R 777 ~/.composer no success

Some build of the same project inside different container is succeeded. My container starts with this volumes:

- project directory
- ~/.ssh directory

I search across net but got no solution. PLease help.

Comment: rm -rf /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---flex.symfony.com && touch /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---flex.symfony.com worked but is there any other solution

Comment: I hope solution is differen from composer update. Because symfony gives not enough memory error and i cant increase this memory limit.

Comment: can't you increase it by using `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer update` ?

Comment: Make your composer install without cache : `composer install --no-cache ...`
Or if you can update flex, it will solve the problem according to Symfony's creator : https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/780

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug on Flex version <1.13.4

In latest version (as I write 1.13.4) the [issue](https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/780) is solved.

The problem was:

> Writing to the cache with an empty key will fail with "failed to open
> stream: Is a directory", so do not try to do that.
>
> We noticed this when cloudflare - or the backend service - responded with a "last-modified" header for our CI servers (AWS) but not for our local system. This triggered the condition to become true and it tries to write a cache file without a filename.

That problem was solved with commit [d81196c3f3b5](https://github.com/symfony/flex/commit/d81196c3f3b544e32997b67e955fb8291fdfe770)

Edit: as posted by @Tmb a workaround is to use: `composer install --no-cache ...`

Comment: had the same issue, clearing the composer cache worked for me.